# Junit - Override default behaviour to run tests only once, even if they are added several times (in different Suites)

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

For our usecase, as an example - we need to run a JUnit test, even if it is added multiple times within a Test Suite, without being skipped.

Currently we notice that JUnit test runner skips a Test with the same name, if it finds the test somewhere else within a Test Suite. Here is an example screenshot to show test "Case_A" within "Procedure_A" being skipped within a Test Suite -

[image]

Could this behaviour be overriden, if so could someone point us in the right direction?

Comment: I assume this is an Eclipse issue no? this works with maven/surefire for example

Comment: Can you post the code to reproduce what you describe?

Answer (score 0):

I did some research arround this problem.

Simple setting - one Test "TestCase_A" and one Suite "TestProcedure_A" that runs the TestCase_A twice :

```
public class TestCase_A {

@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Case_A RUN");
    Assert.assertTrue(true);
  }
}
```

---

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({ TestCase_A.class, TestCase_A.class })
@SuppressWarnings("all")
public class TestProcedure_A {
}
```

I run the test Suite using Eclipse and maven.
Finding: The sysout statement actually shows, that the TestCase_A runs twice!

Therefore, the Eclispe View is misleading. Test are run multiple times - the tree also reflects this. However, the status of the actual single calls is not displayed properly in the Eclispe Junit View.

I presume the view is based on the *junit.runner.TestRunListener*. It probably worth looking into that.

Comment: someone else also found it useful to let JDT filter duplicate tests: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=341778